# Round label values in Grafana visualization chart

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

Given the following grafana logs visualization script:

```
sum by(score) (
  count_over_time(
  {container_name="dal-api"}
  |= update_score_day5
  | logfmt
  | json score="score_service"
  [1d])
)
```

I want to round scores, currently i have too many visualization bars because the results can be 1.3 1.5 2.4 etc

Comment: So what do you want to do? Round values or decrease time granularity of the query result?

Comment: Round the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with [Template functions](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/template_functions/):

```
sum by(score) (
 count_over_time(
  {container_name="dal-api"}
  |= update_score_day5
  | logfmt
  | json
  | score=`{{round .score_service 0}}`
  [1d])
)
```

Here field `score_service` will be preserved as-is (obviously only inside of aggregation), and new field `score` will be added with rounded value. Instead of `round`, you can also use [`ceil`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/template_functions/#ceil) or [`floor`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/template_functions/#floor)

Demo of similar query can be seen [here](https://play.grafana.org/explore?schemaVersion=1&panes=%7B%22AhI%22:%7B%22datasource%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22,%22queries%22:%5B%7B%22refId%22:%22A%22,%22expr%22:%22%7Bfilename%3D%5C%22%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Fjson_access.log%5C%22%7D%20%5Cr%5Cn%7C%20json%20%5Cr%5Cn%7C%20label_format%20%20gzip_ratio_rounded%3D%60%7B%7Bround%20.gzip_ratio%200%7D%7D%60%22,%22queryType%22:%22range%22,%22datasource%22:%7B%22type%22:%22loki%22,%22uid%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22%7D,%22editorMode%22:%22code%22%7D,%7B%22refId%22:%22B%22,%22expr%22:%22sum%20by%28gzip_ratio_rounded%29%20%28%5Cr%5Cncount_over_time%28%5Cr%5Cn%20%7Bfilename%3D%5C%22%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Fjson_access.log%5C%22%7D%20%5Cr%5Cn%20%7C%20json%20%5Cr%5Cn%20%7C%20label_format%20%20gzip_ratio_rounded%3D%60%7B%7Bround%20.gzip_ratio%200%7D%7D%60%5Cr%5Cn%5B1h%5D%29%5Cr%5Cn%29%22,%22queryType%22:%22range%22,%22datasource%22:%7B%22type%22:%22loki%22,%22uid%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22%7D,%22editorMode%22:%22code%22%7D%5D,%22range%22:%7B%22from%22:%22now-5m%22,%22to%22:%22now%22%7D%7D%7D&orgId=1).